# Select control not taking value from two way binding

Tags: angular, angular7

I have the following select control:

```html
<select id="my-select" [(ngModel)]="available" (change)="handleChange($event)">
    <option value="true">Available</option>
    <option value="false">Unavailable</option>
  </select>
```

I am using a two way binding to a property called `available`.  What I want is for the user to be able to set status available/unavailable, a backend method will make a call to the API and if it fails it will display an error message and set the select control back to it's previous state.

To test this I did the following component:

```
import { TextAttribute } from "@angular/compiler/src/render3/r3_ast";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  available: boolean;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.available = false;
  }

  async handleChange(event: Event) {
    // ... some process to set status
    //oops error happened setting status, lets set it back
    this.available = false;
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Stack blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-playground-sapjc8?file=src/app/app.component.ts

What I expect to happen is that user select available and then it instantly gets set back to unavailable but what happens is setting `available` property doesn't change the drop down.

What am I mis-understanding about angular bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that exactly the value of `available` changes in the `handleChange`, but after `change detection` cycle, that's enough for you to use `setTimeout`

```
async handleChange(event: Event) {
  // ... some process to set status
  //oops error happened setting status, lets set it back
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.available = false;
    console.log(event);
  }, 0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a promise or subscription I can use?

Comment: as you said ,if you make a http request in `handleChange` function and change that `available` in the observer, it will automatically update your view and no need to use `setTimeout` (for test you can use somethings that fake a request `interval(1000).pipe(first())`) because `ngZone` monkey patches the observables.